# search and replace with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, strstr

Im trying to implement a 'search and replace all'. I have 2 pointers to monitor characters nclude 
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
const int BUFSIZE = 256;

const char * const SEARCH = "the";
const char * const REPLACE = "Who is John";

int main()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
      Error(SOURCE_FILE);

    //open file for append and update
    fstream destination(DESTINATION_FILE, 
        ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::app);

    //check if destination file is open
    if (!destination.is_open())
        Error(SOURCE_FILE);


        bufPtr += length;               //move bufPtr to point past the SEARCH

        destination << bufPtr;          //write rest of buf to destination
        //destination.seekg(0);

        //write lines from source to destination
        //if(!(destination << buf << '\n'))
            //Error(SOURCE_FILE);
    }   
    source.close();
    destination.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is also http://codereview.stackexchange.com for this kind of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking for the case where `strstr()` doesn't find the search string. It returns `NULL` in that case, and your while loop loop won't do the right thing in that case.